# find rank with the user details SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am struggling with my SQL skills.
I am trying to get the rank of a user in a table and I use the below query found in stackoverflow and it works very well.

```
Select count(brp.*) + 1 From run_progress brp, (SELECT * FROM run_progress WHERE runner = 1 ) p WHERE brp.progress > p.progress;
```

It gives me the correct rank, but I also want to get the details of the 'p' p has the details of the rank person details. How can I do that ?
Hope my question is clear.
Needs to select all columns of 'p'.

thank you

UPDATE

```
CREATE TABLE run_progress
(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   user varchar(255),
   progress numeric
)

INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 9, 1, 100 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 11, 2, 90 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 14, 3, 60 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 10, 4, 10 )
```

This is my table

```
for user:1 it should give me - 1, 9,1,100
for user:4 it should give me - 4, 10,4,100
```

Hope thats clear.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using window functions?  These perform much better and are more powerful:

```
select brp.*
from (SELECT brp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY progress DESC) as seqnum
      FROM runprogress brp
     ) brp
```

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but if you want the ranking for `runner = 1`, then add a `where` clause:

```
select brp.*
from (SELECT brp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY progress DESC) as seqnum
      FROM runprogress brp
     ) brp
where runner = 1;
```

Note:  Your method of ranking gives runners with the same `progress` different rankings, which is why this uses `ROW_NUMBER()`.  If you want ties to have the same score, use either `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2690036b567db9ef9788d7dd776398c5) is a db<>fiddle.